# If A is non-singular and B is nilpotent, with some additional properties, A-B is non-singular?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ be two square matrices of size $n$ with the following properties:

$A$ is non-singular, $a_{ii}=1$ $\ \forall i$, if $a_{ij}\neq 0$ then $a_{ji}= 0$ $\ \forall i,j$ and $i\neq j$;

$B$ is singular, $b_{ii}=0$ $\ \forall i$, if $[b_{i,1},\dots,b_{i,n}]\neq [0,0,...,0]$ then $[b_{1,i},\dots,b_{n,i}]^T= [0,0,...,0]^T$ (i.e. for $i=1,...,n$, the $i$-th row or the $i$-th column or together is completely null).

Is it possible to prove that $A-B$ is non-singular?

What about the non-singularity of $A-B$ if $a_{ij}\geq 0$ and $b_{ij}\geq 0$ $\forall i,j$?

Comment: I don't understand your if-then statement for $A$.  What do we know about the off-diagonal entries of $A$?

Comment: the off-diagonal entris of $A$  are null for a good part, and in particulare if a generic element $a_{i,j}$ is not null, the corresponding simmetric element $a_{j,i}$ is null.

Comment: So it is a typo ? You wrote: if $a_{ij}\neq 0$ then $a_{ij}=0$.

Comment: yes, sorry, it's aa typo. If $a_{ij} \neq 0$ the $a_{ji}=0$

Comment: @Anton, your question's title is pretty misleading: you want to prove this for a **very particular** kind of regular matrices $\;A\;$ . Please do change this.

Comment: Sorry for the misleading in the title, but I didn't know how to describe my problem in a short way

Answer (score 2):

What about $A$=$\left [\begin{array} {rr}
1  &  0\\
1  &  1\\
\end{array}\right]$
and $B$=$\left [\begin{array} {rr}
0  &  -1\\
0  &  0\\
\end{array}\right]$?

$A$ is non singular clearly nonsingular with $\det(A) = 1$, $B$ is nilpotent with $B^{2}=0$, but $A-B$=$\left [\begin{array} {rr}
1  &  1\\
1  &  1\\
\end{array}\right]$ is singular. I think these two matrices meet your criteria as well.

Edit: in response to your comment, I don't believe so. Take $A$ =$\left [\begin{array} {rr}
1  &  1 & 0 \\
0  &  1 & 1\\
0  &  0 & 1
\end{array}\right]$, and $B$=$\left [\begin{array} {rr}
0  &  0 & 0\\
0  &  0 & 0\\
1  &  0 & 0
\end{array}\right]$.

Then $\det(A)=1$, $B^{2} = 0$ and $A-B$=$\left [\begin{array} {rr}
1  &  1 & 0 \\
0  &  1 & 1\\
-1  &  0 & 1
\end{array}\right]$, which if I haven't miscomputed is indeed singular.

Comment: great! Do you think that if I impose  not negative the values of A and B can change anything?

Comment: @Anton: I don't believe so. See my updated answer - I believe this meets your criteria.

Comment: ok, thank you very much!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider $A$=$\left [\begin{array} {rr}
1  &  1\\
0  &  1\\
\end{array}\right]$
and $B$=$\left [\begin{array} {rr}
0  &  0\\
-1  &  0\\
\end{array}\right]$
$A$ is non singular $B$ is nilpotent but $A-B$ is singular

Comment: the condition is $A$ is non-singular

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, the question's title is pretty misleading.

Comment: In my case $a_{ii}=1$ $\forall i$ and If $a_{ij} \neq 0$ the $a_{ji}=0$. So I can not have $A$ as you write...

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: (and OP Anton as well) Could you explain exactly which condition is not met (chapter and verse, notably $i$ and $j$). For $A$, I see that $A_{1,2}\neq0$, but indeed $A_{2,1}=0$ as required, so that's OK; and taking $i=j$ is excluded.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen the answer was changed recently; I hadn't noticed

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: OK thanks; on my part I only had seen the changed answer, not the original one.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: Also, the edit occurred after AWertheim had posted an example, and the edited version is exactly the transpose of that example.